# Queries related to proof of path-connectedness of Toplogist's Sine curve

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness, limsup-and-liminf, path-connected

I've  easily shown that **Topologist's Sine Curve(TSC)** is connected.Now I'm trying to fill the gaps in the following  proof  of **"showing TSC is not path-connected"** .While going through this proof i got some questions,i was unable to answer .

Suppose there is a path $f:[a,c]\rightarrow \bar S,$ from $(0,0)$ to (1,0) in the **Topologist's Sine Curve(TSC)**.

Consider the set of those $t$ for which $f(t)\in 0\times [-1,1]$ is closed,let this set be $K$.So,K is closed(K contains all of its limit points).So, K has a  largest element '**b**'(say) **({1})**.( **check the arguments in  this paragraph,if there is some scope of improvement please let me know** )

Then $f:$[**b**,$c$]$\rightarrow \bar S$ is a path  that maps **b** into the vertical interval {$0$}$\times [-1,1]$ and maps other  points of [b,c] to points of $S$.**({2},{3})**

We relabel the domain as $[0,1]$ for convenience.

let $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, where $y(t)=\sin({\frac{1}{x(t)}})$

As $f$ is continuous,the coordinates $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are continuous as well.

We produce  a sequence   $<t_n>\rightarrow 0$ in $[0,1]$ such that $y(t_n)\not\to y(0)$,which violates the sequential criteria for convergence in Metric spaces.

Since,$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \bar S$ is a path.

So,$f(0)=x(0)$  and $f(t)=y(t)$ for $t>0$.

But,$f(0)=0$,So,$x(0)=0$ and $f(t)=y(t)$ for $t>0$.

Now,$x(0)=0$ and $y(t)=\sin (\frac{1}{x(t)})$ for $t>0$.

To find $<t_n>$,we proceed as follows:

Given $n$,choose $u$ with $0<u<x(\frac{1}{n})$ such that $\sin(\frac{1}{u})=(-1)^n$.

Since,$x(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.So, by intermediate value theorem there exists $t_n\in (0,\frac{1}{n})$ such that $x(t_n)=u$ i.e.,$\sin(\frac{1}{u})=\sin(\frac{1}{x(t_n)})=y(t_n)=(-1)^n.$**({4})**

Collection of queries from the above proof-

> $1.$ Is "b" largest limit point of $K$?
>
> $2.$ How can a single point b be mapped to $0\times [-1,1]$?
>
> $3.$ How we're so sure that it is only the largest element b which is
>   mapped on the vertical line?
>
> $4.$ What is explicit representation of $t_n$?

Reference:Topology by J.R.Munkres(2nd ed.)

Comment: In the paragraph {1}, note that preimage of a compact set may not be compact.

Comment: @CaveJohnson:But,what to do with pre-image  of the compact set?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but how do you conlude that $K$ is compact?

Comment: @CaveJohnson:K being the subset of compact set $0\times [-1,1]$ is compact(As every open cover of K has a  finite subcover,which is proper or improper subset of the finite cover of $0\times [-1,1]$).

Comment: Then there should be two problems: your definition of $K$ is incorrect(which seems to be a typo); subset of compact set is not necessarily compact(e.g. $(0,1)\subset[0,1]$).

Comment: @CaveJohnson:You caught me;-).It is given in Munkres toplogy that K is closed,then there must be some other way of showing K to be closed.

Comment: @CaveJohnson:What is it?

Comment: @CaveJohnson:I think misinterpretted  the sentence in the book.It is written"The set of those $t$ for which $f(t)\in 0\times [-1,1]$  is closed".So,by definition K is closed,so here is no need to use Tychonoff's theorem

Comment: That looks fine :-)

Comment: @CaveJohnson:What are you opinions about other questions?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough time now to check all the details... The idea of the proof looks OK for me, maybe others on this site could help you check those details.

Comment: @CaveJohnson:No problem...Have a nice day ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As remarked by Cave Johnson, $K$ is not a subset of $L  = \{ 0 \} \times [-1,1]$. In fact $K = f^{-1}(L) \subset [a,b]$. It is *closed* in $[a,b]$ because $f$ is continuous and  $L$ is closed in $\overline{S}$. Hence $K$ is compact.

You correctly define $b$ as the maximum of $K$ (which is of course unique) and consider the restriction $f : [b,c] \to \overline{S}$. But then $f(b) \in L$ because $b \in K$ and $f(t) \in S$ for $t > b$ because $t \notin K$. Of course, all $t \in K \setminus \{ b \}$ are also mapped by $f$ into $L$, but this does not play any role.

The rest of your proof is absolutely correct. However, the $t_n$ cannot be explicitly represented unless you have an explict formula for $f$.

Comment: :How did you conclude that K is compact?

Comment: :Very much agreeing with your last comment about the form of $<t_n>$.But,how can one gets the confirmation that $t_n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact and $[a,b]$ is compact. Alternatively you can consider the supremum $b$ of $K$ which always exists. For each $n$ you find $k_n \in K$ such that $b - k_n < 1/n$, hence $k_n \to b$ and $b \in K$ because $K$ is closed. The $t_n$ have been **chosen** in $(0,1/n)$, therefore $t_n \to 0$.

Comment: :Thanks a lot!!